# red5 client in android

Tags: java, android, red5

Is it possible to create a red5 client for android ?

I have already used red5 in flash and in java desktop application and I think there is a way to use it in Android.

Is there any sample of a red5 live video stream shown on an android view ?

Comment: Dear Joel,My current project is on Red5 server. Will you provide some samples on red5 server in java(client side and server side).Please....

Comment: Did you find anything on this??? I'm also interested in this...thanks in advance!!! :)

Comment: Yes i have found this: It is not possible.

Comment: Hey Joel, would you mention the features of your Red5 Java client?
for example: Connect to red5 from java desktop(jnlp) client, publish webcam feed to Red5 server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible to create red5 client for android.
At the moment I developing red5 chat and have working prototype of AIR application which connect to red5 server.
Dont forget to give network permissions to your android app

You can find working red5 clients applications in Google Play. For example, [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.vchaterMobile&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImFpci52Y2hhdGVyTW9iaWxlIl0.)